# How to create a list where items have different controllers in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list which can contain different types of things that need a different template / controller.  Whats the best way to do this in angular js.

The best i've come up with so far is to have the template as part of the ng-repeat data.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="foo in list">
    <div ng-include src="'partials/'+foo.template+'.template.html'">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

where the list is something like.

```
[{template:'foo',data:{...}},{template:'bar',data:{...}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks good to me, you don't even need the `<div>` tags since you can attach ng-include to the `<li>` tags (I think).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a directive like this http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/